# Type Error In bootstrap tagsinput

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, typeerror, bootstrap-tags-input

I want to use the Bootstrap Input Tags. But it seems that I'm getting a TypeError.In the console this messages is showing

> TypeError: elt.tagsinput is not a function

Here is my code

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
                var members = JSON.constructor({!!  json_encode($member)  !!});
                var arr = [];
                var mem = new Bloodhound({
                    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('text'),
                    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                    local: members
                });
                mem.initialize();
                var elt = $('#researcher');
                console.log(members);
                console.log(typeof(elt));
                elt.tagsinput({
                    itemValue: 'value',
                    itemText: 'text',
                    allowDuplicates: false,
                    interactive:true,
                    typeaheadjs: {
                        name: 'mem',
                        displayKey: 'text',
                        source: mem.ttAdapter()
                    }
                });
    </script>
```

I am using the following libraries:

1. https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js
2. https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css
3. https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js
4. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.js
5. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.css
6. https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js

Can anyone help me out?